# Google API server key

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

There is a map route [library](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary) for android, which requires server API key. The point is that when I'm trying to obtain the key, it does not change the restriction mode from "NONE" to "IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.)" unless I specify the optional field "IP addresses". Is there any way to change the mode without that?

Comment: https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android refer this

Comment: @GowthamanM thanks I'll try

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/13373/android-google-map-drawing-route-two-points# refer this link will give better solution.

Comment: is there any problem let me know

Comment: @GowthamanM , thank u, I've already solved using 1st link! That lib is extremely helpful

Comment: you are welcome,happy to help.@ionson